# How to group by and count each item of serialized array?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, group-by

I'm storing a list of items in a serialized array within a field in my database (I'm using PHP/MySQL).
Each user have this serialized array in own table. I need to count how many user has one item of the serialized array.

**For example:**

serialized array may contains(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

**user a;**
a:2:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:1:"7";}

**user b;**
a:1:{i:0;s:1:"6";}

**user c;**
a:3:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:1:"7";i:2;s:1:"2";}

**i need this result;**

count("0") = 0

count("1") = 0

count("2") = 1

count("3") = 0

count("4") = 0

count("5") = 0

count("6") = 3

count("7") = 2

count("8") = 0

Hopefully that makes sense.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: MySQL cannot work with that format. You will have to retrieve the entries and do the counting/grouping yourself. Btw, CSV is a format databases at least work with; otherwise put the entries into a separate user_id-related table.

Comment: It would be easier if you stored those numbers in separate table. `user_id | number`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two loops.

```
$arrCount = array();
foreach($arrUsers $user_key=>$count_data){
foreach($count_data => $val){
   if(isset($arrCount[$val]))
   {
       $arrCount[$val]++;
   }else{
       $arrCount[$val] = 1;
   }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple function, that walks through every single userarray. Notice that I unserialize the array before counting. This code will give the desirable result.

```
<?php

function countElement($userArray, $value) {
    $cnt = 0;
    if(!empty($userArray)) {
        foreach($userArray as $user) {
            $unserializeArr = unserialize($user);
            $tmp = array_count_values($unserializeArr);
            if(isset($tmp[$value])) $cnt += $tmp[$value];
        }
    }
    return $cnt;
}

$userArr = array();
$userArr[] = 'a:2:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:1:"7";}';
$userArr[] = 'a:1:{i:0;s:1:"6";}';
$userArr[] = 'a:3:{i:0;s:1:"6";i:1;s:1:"7";i:2;s:1:"2";}';

for($i = 0; $i <= 8; $i++) {
    echo 'Count('.$i.') = '.countElement($userArr, $i).'<br>';
}

?>
```